# Unit testing angular reactive form select dropdowns

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have been unable to figure out how to test a select dropdown in a reactive form in Angular.

I followed the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview#testing-reactive-forms) for how to test reactive forms and it works fine on inputs with some minor tweaking, but I can't get it to function for a select.

Say I have this select

HTML

```
<div class="form-field">
  <label for="contactSuffix">Suffix</label>
  <select id="contactSuffix" formControlName="contactSuffix">
      <option value="mr">MR</option>
      <option value="mrs">MRS</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

And I am trying to test it using the same method that works for inputs

```
  it('should update the value of the contactSuffix field', () => {
    const contactSuffix = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('#contactSuffix');
    contactSuffix.value = 'mr';
    contactSuffix.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    expect(component.stepForm.controls['contactSuffix'].value).toEqual('mr');
  });
```

I am getting this error running the test
`Expected '' to equal 'mr'.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try triggering change event instead of the input event.

I'd do something like this:

```
it('should update the value of the contactSuffix field', () => {
  const contactSuffix = fixture.nativeElement.querySelector('#contactSuffix');
  contactSuffix.value = 'mr';
  contactSuffix.dispatchEvent(new Event('change')); 
  fixture.detectChanges(); // Trigger change detection

  expect(component.stepForm.controls['contactSuffix'].value).toEqual('mr');
});
```